# mySQL record with latest status=1 in second table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table A

```
|    id    |    Name    |
_________________________
|    1     |    ABC     |
_________________________
|    2     |    BCD     |
_________________________
```

Table B

```
|    id    |    a_id    |    Status    |    timestamp    |
__________________________________________________________
|    1     |    1       |       1      |    timestamp    |
__________________________________________________________
|    2     |    1       |       2      |    timestamp    |
__________________________________________________________
|    3     |    1       |       3      |    timestamp    |
__________________________________________________________
|    4     |    2       |       1      |    timestamp    |
__________________________________________________________
```

In above example I only want to pick

```
|    name  |    a_id    |    Status    |    timestamp    |
__________________________________________________________
|    BCD   |    2       |       1      |    timestamp    |
```

So with any record that has ONLY and ONLY latest STATUS as 1, I want to pick that record.. If the LATEST STATUS is 2 or 3, I don't want ot pick them...

If possible I don't want to use sub-query because I am using Codeigniter which doesn't really like subqueries.

Please help

Comment: It's simple enough without a subquery, but without proper DDLs I can't really be bothered. (Although presumably codeigniter can also use views - in which case, what's the problem with a subquery)

Comment: I don't know CodeIgniter, but have you tried this: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Subqueries? Seems to solve your problems of subqueries. I don't think it can be done without..

Comment: No problem with sub-query really, I wanted to know if it can be done without sub-query, thought will learn something new

@nickyvV: I have tried it, I don't really want to change anything in system files, I can use custom queries though, just have to make sure they are clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So that will be:

```
SELECT
  A.name,
  B.*
FROM
    (SELECT 
       a_id, 
       MAX(`timestamp`) AS max_timestamp
     FROM B 
     GROUP BY a_id) AS latest
    LEFT JOIN B
      ON 
        B.a_id=latest.a_id
        AND
        B.`timestamp`=latest.max_timestamp
    LEFT JOIN A
      ON B.a_id=A.id
WHERE
  B.status=1
```

As for subquery - I doubt you can retrieve desired information without that in single query. That is because you need to use row set, which is a result of grouping by one column, in reference to another column. And so you need to group that first, and then apply `JOIN` to result row set.

Comment: Great, but he mentioned he does not want sub-query :)

Comment: Agreed. I don't think it's possible because of need in referring to grouped by one column rowset from another column. Not in single query.

Comment: Yah, I will use sub-query.. just wanted to know if there is a way around to do it without sub-query.. I am trying this query, hope it works...

Comment: Yes. It's possible without a subquery (although invariably slower on larger data sets), as explained in the manual.

Comment: @Strawberry could you please post it then? I'd like to see

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Strawberry for pointing to this article, I figured a way to do it for this example.

```
select a.name
      ,b1.a_id
      ,b1.status
      ,b1.`timestamp` AS b1Time
FROM TableA a
JOIN TableB b1 ON b1.a_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN TableB b2 ON b2.a_id = b1.a_id AND b1.`timestamp` < b2.`timestamp`
WHERE b2.`timestamp` IS NULL
AND b1.status = 1
```

See this [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5622f/26).

Comment: which query do you recommend, which one will be faster when we have tables snowed with data?